# meteor mongodb $gte and $lte not working together

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to return documents between tow ranges of dates.
start date ('ordersDateRangeStart') is Mon Nov 07 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST)
end date ('ordersDateRangeEnd') is Thu Nov 24 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST)

```
restOrdersRangeArchive: function () {
    var cursor =  RestOrders.find({
        $and: [
            {restRefId: Router.current().params.Id}, {isStatus: 'archived'}, {
                orderedAt: {
                    $gte: Session.get('ordersDateRangeStart') //, $lte: Session.get('ordersDateRangeEnd')
                }
            }
        ]
    }, {sort: {orderedAt: -1}});
    console.log(cursor);
    return cursor
}
```

The code above works as long as I don't remove the "//" before:
, $lte: Session.get('ordersDateRangeEnd')

so to summarise, when adding the $lte to the query i get no results.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample document?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
{"$and":[{ orderedAt: {$gte: Session.get('ordersDateRangeStart')}},
{ orderedAt: {$lte: Session.get('ordersDateRangeEn' } }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add,keep in mind the time zone difference between local and that in the db if the server is in a timezone different from client when dealing with dates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, the code I pasted is OK, I had issue with the Sessions objects....
Thanks a lot.